# How to select resource for different resolutions in cocos2dx ios using c++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am making different images for iphone and ipad. I have two different images of background but I kept the name of the file bg1.png for both. I put the ipad resolution file in ipad folder and iphone resolution file in iphone4 folder in my resource. My mode is landscape so the height becomes width and width is height
.In my AppDelegate.cpp in didfinishlaunch function I put the following code

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
// initialize director

std::vector<std::string> searchPath;

CCSize winSize=CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

CCDirector* pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
CCEGLView* pEGLView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

pDirector->setOpenGLView(pEGLView);

// turn on display FPS
pDirector->setDisplayStats(true);

// set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
pDirector->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);


if(pDirector->getWinSize().height>=768)
{ 
 CCLOG("if width = %f",pDirector->getWinSize().height);

    searchPath.push_back("ipad");
   // CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPath);
}
else if(pDirector->getWinSize().height<768)
{
    CCLOG("else width = %f",pDirector->getWinSize().height);

    searchPath.push_back("iphone4");

}
    CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->setSearchPaths(searchPath);

// create a scene. it's an autorelease object
CCScene *pScene = HelloWorld::scene();

// run
pDirector->runWithScene(pScene);

return true;
}
```

Every time it is coming in the if block but every alternate time it shows the different images. Suppose if I run for the first time it shows the ipad image. Then i stop the build and re run the code, then it shows iphone image. But I am using the Ipad simulator in both the case. Is anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Probably nothing wrong with your code. The cocos2dx assets search code is a bit "weird" and uses some strange caching strategy to avoid researching. We ended up wrapping all "filenames" in a function call that prefixed them with e.g. "@2x_" so there is no filename aliasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you build your project - compiler copy your resources files to root of application folder. And sometimes it's copy last file for iphone, some times for ipad (it's overwrite previous file). So check that the folders "ipad" & "iphone4" has blue color in your project. That means that this folder will be copy as it (with subdirs/files inside).

When you drag&drop this resources to your project - you should select "Create folder references for any added folders" in popup dialog: [image]

Btw you can check struct of your files in builded application. Just build app for simulator and then find location of your project by path `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/DF7882AE-FF34-4D2F-A42C-25317785212B/AppNameHere.app/...` where:

```
7.1 - version of iOS Simulator
DF7882AE-FF34-4D2F-A42C-25317785212B - app-id in simulator
```

---

**Added answer for:** *I want to ask that android devices are in so many dimensions. What is the best resource size dimension...*

For any project the structure of resources maybe different. For example in my last project I use next one. I have 3 kind of dimensions:

```
nd (normal definition) - for iPhone-retina & iPad-non-retina
md (mini definition)   - for iPhone-non-retina (with sizes of images scaled 0.5x of "normal")
hd (high definition)   - for iPad-retina (with sizes of images scaled 2x of "normal")
```

On app launch I look at device screen size (in pixels) and decide what to use:

```
cocos2d::Size size = cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

if( size.width >= 1920 && size.height >= 1280 )
    cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("images-hd");
else if( size.width >= 960  && size.height >= 640 )
    cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("images-nd");
elsewhere
    cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("images-md");
```

And all my sprites, menu, backgrounds, etc I set positions with logic of 3 kind of dimensions.
And I don't think about "hdpi,xhdpi,mdpi,ldpi".

You can find Dim source here: https://github.com/duksel/Cocos2dx-DukselLib/tree/master/etc
In that class implemented detection of resolution and creating Point, Size, float values by dimenstion value.

Comment: this worked. Thanks. But will it work for android because in android there is no such create reference for added folder option. Can you tell it for android

Comment: When you will build apk file the builder-script will copy all your files from `Resources` folder to `assets` folder with same structure. So put your `ipad` & `iphone4` in the root of `Resources` folder.

Comment: By the way you can build `assets` folder from differents sources. For example, in some of my projects I have specific resources only for android version of application. So in file `proj.android/build-cfg.json` for key `copy_resources` I define a few rules what need to copy to result `assets` dir.

Comment: Thanks .I want to ask that android devices are in so many dimensions. What is the best resource size dimension for it so that I dont have to put so many different dimension images in assets and the game work perfectly in almost all devices (hdpi,xhdpi,mdpi,ldpi etc).
What should be the resolution that I should take for android?

Comment: @Rajan - Look at my 1st post with added answer to your question.

Comment: thanks @Andrei. But still we require 3 dimension of images.Suppose if my resource size of ipad retina is 10 MB. I have to take iphone images + ipad images. So this will lead to increase in my app size from 10 MB to let's say 18 19 MB. Any other solution if we have? One solution is that We can do scaling using setscaleX and setscaleY functions provided by framework, But this will lead the decrease the app performance in iphone as the ipad retina size image (2048X1536) have to be bought in iphone RAM and then accordingly scaled. Therefore leading to performance issues

Comment: You answered on your question by yourself. Increase app size is not a big problem :) But use ipad-retina-images for ipad/iphone is really bad idea (it'll decrease performance & will have problem with RAM). Also you can make 2 separated versions of ipad+tables && iphone+phone. But is that really need? Btw, if you use PNG files you can try this service http://tinypng.com. All my images it decrease for ~60-70%